# How can I keep operators in Latin Modern when changing the main text font and language?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, times, text-mode, timesfont

Is there a way to turn the operators sin and cos (and all the other operators lim,inf,...) in latin (default) mode and the text remains always in greek times new roman font?

[image: When I write in math mode i get this one]

[image: But I want this math font]

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
```

I have written this code. I want the cos operator to be as shown in the second picture, but it does not. What's the problem? Can someone help?

Comment: please provide a full but minimal example such that others know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Hm, if you write math operators as `\cos`, `\sin` etx, that will always appear in latin letters as cos, sin ... As example please test `\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}


\begin{document}
Ελλάδα, ... $\cos(\alpha)$
\end{document}`

Comment: None of these work. I added two pictures. It appears the first one, but I want the second one.

Comment: @panosPhysics Can you please add a small test document to your question?

Comment: I added the code. Please, can someone help?

Comment: The second picture is Computer Modern (or Latin Modern), the default font, rather than Times.

Comment: Welcome. // @panosPhysics, did you try to copy and compile the code you posted? If it fails, please EDIT your code. Minimalistic means it has all needed to show your problem, and leaves out all the rest. Thanks

Comment: The code you've supplied isn't sufficient.  Please extend it to begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  Off topic: don't load `amsmath` more than once.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Also, how do I put the real numbers set R back in latin mode?

Comment: I'd rather use a math font matching Times than mix Latin Modern Math with Times: they're visually incompatible.